Exclude implicit modules in jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not work
We have an application that is currently running on jboss 8 after a migration from java 11 to java 17. The problem is that we currently have some unit tests failing and through debbug we understand that the jakarta.el.api jar which is in our ear file is being overwritten by the same jar with a different version that jboss is bringing implicitly. Below is the module.xml of the jakarta.el.api that jboss is bringing
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9" name="jakarta.el.api">
<resources>
<resource-root path="jboss-el-api_5.0_spec-4.0.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="java.desktop"/>
</dependencies>
</module>

We realized that the version was not that of our jar, when we saw the class loader of an object:
ModuleClassLoader for Module "jakarta.el.api" version 4.0.1.Final-redhat-00001 from local module loader @41294f8 (finder: local module finder @225129c (roots: /app/jboss/modules,/app/jboss/modules /system/layers/base))
we need our application to look at the jar version of jakarta.el.api that is in our ear file
We've already tried a lot to add this module to the exclusions section of jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but nothing changes:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
     <deployment>
         <exclusions>
             <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j.api" />
             <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
             <module name="org.slf4j" />
             <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
             <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
             <module name="jakarta.el.api" />
             <module name="org.glassfish.expressly" />
         </exclusions>
         <exclude-subsystems>
             <subsystem name="webservices" />
             <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
         </exclude-subsystems>
     </deployment>
    
     @SUB_DEPLOYMENTS@
    
</jboss-deployment-structure>


What version are you including in your EAR?

Version 5.0.0
For example, I want to use the ELContext.convertToType method from version 5.0.0, which is the version present in the EAR. The implementation of this method shown in my IDE is from version 5.0.0, but behind the scenes, the application is actually calling the version 4.0.1 of this method

When you say "jboss 8" do you mean JBoss EAP 8? If that is the case it already ships with Jakarta Expression Language 5.0. The version 4.0.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar is the version of the forked API.
